# Create a weekly timetable using CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a weekly timetable of classes for a yoga studio.
I have created a static version using a table which you can see at:

<strike>http://www.studioleisure.com/classes.php</strike>

<strike>Note: ^^ This webpage now contains the finished HTML version that was created using the answers to this question.</strike>

I have problem with classes that start at 15 minutes past the hour or ones that last longer than an hour and it's turning out quite difficult to create the PHP for this version.

I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas to create one that would have a similar look but be easier to code the PHP for.

Comment: What is "the PHP" supposed to do exactly?

Comment: I want the data for the timetable to come from a database

Comment: Looks good how it is at the moment.

Comment: @Max what aspect of the operation are you stuck with? The look of the static page can surely be achieved by a PHP script as well

Comment: I'd assume that it's more difficult to get the HTML/CSS to work in this case?

Comment: I'm not really stuck it's just I was thinking there may be a better way to do this. Also i'll have to add lots more rows to support 15 mins past.

Comment: I think this question might be a bit to vague for stack overflow :P

Comment: What have you got so far in the way of PHP code?

Comment: Nothing really, I was just wondering if anyone could think of a different way that may be easier to code. If you can think of any useful PHP for this I would appreciate it!

Comment: If I was you I would smear the PHP all over the calendar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd loose the table, and use only columns. Then I'd place the classes with CSS (`position:absolute`) and calculate the `top`value based on their start time and the 'height' based on their length. The horizontal lines could be achieved using a repeating background image. The labels on the left could be placed the same way you'd be placing the classes.

HTML could look something like this:

```
<ul>
 <!-- Monday: -->
 <li>
  <strong>Monday</strong>
  <ul class="classes">
   <li style="top:200px; height:100px;">
    <span>10:30 - 11:45</span>
    Class title
   </li>
   <li>
    <!-- More classes here... -->
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <!-- Other days here... -->
 </li>
</ul>
<ul class="labels">
 <li style="top:180px">10:00</li>
 <!-- More labels here... -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh thanks for spending the time writing all that out! I will give both answers a try, thanks!

Comment: Yours does seem to have better SEO so I will go for yours first! :)

Comment: Please prove me wrong, but I think that you'll kill yourself trying to achieve this effect across browsers using tables ;) — Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Nice markup. But you're right - doing this with a fine granularity will result in a monster of a table (and the accompanying code for generating it). It's doable, but there is an easier way, although it's not so neat:

Create the table as you usually would, but make it empty. However set fixed widths/heights for each row and column. Then use absolute positioning to place the calendar entries **on top of the table**. Presto - it looks the same, but you can place the entries with minute precisions if you want to.

The downside of this is that copy-paste won't work (very well) on this beast, and I've no idea what it will do for SEO and accessibility. Probably nothing good. So if those two are important to you, you will have to resort to workarounds (though I think there are ways to use the scheme *AND* have good SEO/accessibility).

**Added:** Oh, and I just realized that you will also have to watch for overflowing texts. Table cells would expand automatically, but absolutely positioned DIVs won't.

**Added 2:** Hey, here's an idea: use relative positioning to shift the entries a bit. Instead of writing the text directly in the cells, write them inside a SPAN and then relatively position it so it shifts down for the necessary 15 minutes. Again this calls for fixed widths and heights of cells, and overflow will be an issue, but SEO/accessibility won't get hurt, and copy-paste will work as expected.

Comment: ahh good you worked out my vague question! That's perfect. I more concerned with getting something that works than SEO at the moment.

Comment: That sounds like also a good idea. I will deffo try all the methods you guys thought of. You guys are so helpful. Stack overflow rocks!

Answer (score 0):

Following is a Weekly time schedule template I have created.

```
https://github.com/NisalSP9/Weekly-time-schedule-template-jquery
```

And this is running example of it.

```
https://codepen.io/nisalsp9/pen/QqqvwZ?editors=1111
```